# Removing hyphen from JSON

Tags: json, string, magento

I am using this JSON code with OWEBIA Shipping 2.0 to create an shipping method on my magento store:

```
 {  "demo": {       "label": "3 dias úteis",        "conditions":
 "({cart.price+tax+discount} > 59.89) && ({shipto.postcode} > 88000000)
 && ({shipto.postcode} < 88124999)",        "fees": 10,         "customer_groups":
 "3"    } }
```

It works fine, but the Brazilian Zip Code uses a hyphen!
It would be like this xxxxx-xxx
How do I remove the "-" from the string that the user inserts on the field?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As long as i remember Magento is PHP based so you 1st need to do this:

```
$response = json_decode($json_response); // this will convert the json object into php array;
```

Then in order to avoid removing all hypens (if you need them anywhere else) search for the property with the postcode and do this:

```
$postcode_without_hyphens = str_replace('-','', $response->post_code); //example
```

Regards! Please tell me if you need any further help or explanation! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

I think I cant use PHP. Please take a look at this pic:
http://tinypic.com/3ia3s8lt
There is an specific input field for the JSON code.

Comment: This means you have to do what i wrote in the form where users input their post codes :). Simple as that. Read the post data from the form and remove hyphens there. And yes, you can use php since Magento is written on php only. 

Regards and luck! :)

Comment: I would spend days on that! Is there another way? A code to be inserted in the box I´ve shown? :D

Comment: you can apply my method either on the profile page or on the submit page of the shipping. In other words when you send the information before those calculations are done.

Comment: I see! I really appreciate your help. But I am not a developer, just a merchant :)
This is why it would take me ages! hahahaha

Answer (score 1):

It's too late?

I had the same problem. But inspecting the Owebia code i found the solution.

The solution is add a validator to allow only numbers in postcode:

*File: app/code/community/Owebia/Shipping2/Model/ConfigParser.php Line 152*

Change this function:

```
protected function _extract($data, $attributes)
{
    $extract = array();
    foreach ($attributes as $to => $from) {
        $extract[$to] = isset($data[$from]) ? $data[$from] : null;
    }
    return $extract;
}
```

To this:

```
protected function _extract($data, $attributes)
{
    $extract = array();
    foreach ($attributes as $to => $from) {
        // Here we validate the info, check if the current attribute is the postcode
        if($from == "dest_postcode"){
            //So we use preg_replace to allow only digits
            $data[$from] = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $data[$from]);
        }
        $extract[$to] = isset($data[$from]) ? $data[$from] : null;
    }
    return $extract;
}
```